# Call Azure Function from Custom React Microsoft Teams Tab Application in secure way

Tags: reactjs, azure-functions, microsoft-teams

I have created an azure function. I want this azure function to be only accessible for people who are using my Custom React Microsoft Teams Tab Application.

How can I do that

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a very detailed question as there are many aspects to security, but here are some starting points:

1. you could look to ensure your users are, at least, logged in to Office 365, or even specifically to a certain tenant. [MSAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-overview) would help with this, which is Microsoft's client-side Javascript authentication library for authenticating against Azure AD
2. You could look to add authentication into the Azure Function as well - see [here](https://www.voitanos.io/blog/securing-an-azure-function-app-with-azure-ad-works-with-with-sharepoint-framework) for an example.
3. Using the browser's built in CORS capability is also a very easy thing to implement. [Here's](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/handling-cors-in-azure-function/) an example of that - it will block user browsers to only calling the function from your own domain (wherever your tab is hosted).

Of course, none of these is foolproof, but they should give you some good starting points.